# Angular 4 Materialize css sidenav button only works when reload page

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular, materialize

I have an Angular 4 App and It starts with a Login screen and then it goes to the homepage, the homepage is the first page that uses the sidenav. When I make my screen smaller I get the button to show the sidenav. When I click on it, it does not work, however when I reload the page it works.

So I use the same code as given on Materialize CSS and the script I put in index.html in the body.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Solventure</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
        rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
  <style>

  </style>
  <script>
    (function ($) {
      $(function () {

        $('.button-collapse').sideNav({
          edge: 'left', // Choose the horizontal origin
          closeOnClick: true // Closes side-nav on <a> clicks, useful for Angular/Meteor
        });

      }); // end of document ready
    })(jQuery); // end of jQuery name space
  </script>
</head>
<body>


<app></app>

</body>
</html>
```

login.html

```
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="centered-content">
      <img src="../../../favicon.png">
      <form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && login()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !username.valid }">
          <label>Username</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" [(ngModel)]="model.username" #username="ngModel"
                 required/>
          <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !username.valid" class="help-block">Username is required</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !password.valid }">
          <label>Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" [(ngModel)]="model.password" #password="ngModel"
                 required/>
          <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !password.valid" class="help-block">Password is required</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="button-set">
          <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
          <a [routerLink]="['/register']" class="btn btn-link">Register</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <alert></alert>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

home.html

```
<div style="position:absolute;
     min-height:100%; width: 100%">
  <div style="max-width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y:hidden; margin: 0 auto">
    <nav class="toolbar">
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><img src="../../../../logo.png"></a>
        <label class="title-solv">App</label>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right">
          <li class="usericon"><i class="large material-icons">perm_identity</i></li>
          <li class="username">{{username}}</li>
          <li>
            <i [routerLink]="['/login']" class="large material-icons">power_settings_newt</i>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <ul id="slide-out" [ngClass]="{'hide': flag}" class="side-nav fixed  own">
    <li [ngClass]="{'activated': isValid1 }"><a (click)="m1()" class="whitecolor">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li [ngClass]="{'activated': isValid2 }"><a (click)="m2()" class="whitecolor">Dataset Management</a></li>
    <li [ngClass]="{'activated': isValid3 }"><a (click)="m3()" class="whitecolor">Forecast</a></li>
    <li [ngClass]="{'activated': isValid4 }"><a (click)="m4()" class="whitecolor">Reporting</a></li>
    <li [ngClass]="{'activated': isValid5}"><a (click)="m5()" class="whitecolor">Indicator Cloud</a></li>
  </ul>


  <div class="home">
    <div class="webbox">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>

<footer class="footerclass">
</footer>

</div>
```

Comment: Please provide your code, can't do much without that.

Comment: @Nehal I added the 3 html files, and when i click on the loginbutton of the login.html, I go to home, where the navbar is defined.